# Send SMS to multiple recipients using Arduino AT commands

Tags: gsm, at-command, arduino-uno

I have been working on sending SMS to multiple recipients through AT commands. I have been modifying the code that I attached to this post.

Last night I got to know from [this site here](http://www.developershome.com/sms/sendSmsByAtCommands.asp)     that we ought to use the AT+CMSS in order to send multiple sms. And that it sends message from the sms storage area in sim. I tried through this way:

```
  gsm.print("AT+CMGF=1\r");
  delay(100);
  gsm.println("AT + CMSS=3,\"*********\"");
  gsm.println("AT + CMSS=3,\"***********\"");
  gsm.println("AT + CMSS=3,\"**********\"");
  delay(100);
  gsm.println((char)26);                       
  delay(100); 
  gsm.println();
  delay(5000);                                    
  gsmpower();
```

It's working for me but only sending message to the first number. Can you please suggest me the way to use AT+CMSS command?

Comment: Did u achieve this?

Comment: Yes, I did. I ran the above corrected code in a loop. Then it did.